# Test Kendo Combobox with Selenium / Specflow

Tags: c#, selenium, combobox, kendo-ui

I'm trying to test a Kendo combobox with Specflow. Seems, that selenium commands do not work with the combobox. So I tried to use the JavaScriptExecutor.
The Javascript works with the dev console in the chrome browser. But the same command does not work with the JavaScriptExecutor.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementbyId("testElement").value='TEST';");
```

In the test I get a WebDriverException: javascript error: Cannot set property 'value' of null

So it seems that the element was not found...?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the Id of the element is newly generated when the site is loaded. Therefor I get the exception in the test.